# Battery Draining Faster than expected

Tags: battery, battery-life

Can someone help me take a look at my stats? I was wondering why my phone is draining faster than I thought it would.

As you can see, it's down 98% and Screen is on for just 7M in 23minutes time.

Time in the screenshot is 7:04 and currently it's 7:26AM - I now have 93% of battery.

I noticed these two running as similar as to my battery runtime:
1. No Data Connection
2. No or Unknown Signal

Please help me figure out what's the issue and how to resolve it. Thanks!

[BetterBatteryStats](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3061388&d=1418426969)
[LOGCAT BBS](http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=3061389&d=1418426969)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I won't say this is un-natural. Would suggest you to take a longer time period as test period and see the drain.

Setting the brightness to automatic should help reduce the overall usage somewhat.